# PHP- number_format always returns 0.00, while passing a string value

Tags: php

I have the following value, while reading from a csv:

```
1000000
2040000
```

i want this to display:

```
1000000.00
2040000.00
```

I'm using:

```
number_format((int)$line[10], 2, '.', '');
```

but i always get 0.00

What am i doing wrong here? Can someone please help me?

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct array index? Can you show `var_dump($line);`?

Comment: `number_format()` doesn't modify the variable, you need to use the result. E.g. `echo number_format(...);`

Comment: this is what i get:
[10]=> string(15) "1000000"
string(15) "2040000"

Comment: @Barmar I'm testing with:

echo number_format((float)$line[10], 2, '.', '') . '<br>';
and
echo number_format((int)$line[10], 2, '.', '') . '<br>';

Comment: If it's an integer, there's no point in calling `number_format()`, since the fraction is always `.00`. You can simply write `$line[10] . ".00"`

Comment: `string(15)` means there are 15 characters in the string, but `1000000` is only 7 characters long. What are the other 8 characters in the string? Maybe it has leading spaces? That would explain why it's being converted to `0`. Try using `(float)trim($line[10])`

Comment: i think it has many zeros, which seems to be the problem. The $line[10] . ".00" solution should do the trick i guess

Comment: That's not what you showed above.

Comment: i have 3 rows with line[10], each has length of 7 and 1 with length of 1. Could that be the reason why it's showing 15?

Comment: No, that's not why. You're dumping each of them separately, it's only 7 characters each time.

Comment: Try doing the dump inside `<pre>` block, you'll probably see all the spaces. Or just look at the CSV file, there are probably spaces after the comma.

Comment: @Barmar with <pre> i get:
[10] => 
[10] => 1000000
[10] => 2040000

i checked the csv, there are no spaces

Comment: Where did the `string(15)` go? Did you change from `var_dump` to `print_r`? It leaves out important information, don't use it.

Comment: yes i did sorry. With var_dump i get:
[10]=> string(1)
[10]=> string(15) "1000000"
[10]=> string(15) "2040000"

I have no idea, why it says 15, because there are only 7 digits. Do you think i have to escape special characters?

Comment: Something else is in the strings, I don't know what it is. But it's preventing the strings from being parsed as numbers, and that's your problem. Please post the formatted output in the question, spacing is lost in comments.

Comment: @Barmar you're absolutely right on this one. There is something in between and i think i know why. Because the csv has been edited with a Notepad and there hidden characters. Something to do with encoding, that were probably preventing the string from being converted. I tried with a normal conversion from excel to csv and it worked!

Comment: Maybe it's using UTF-16 encoding.

Comment: yes most probably. Thanks alot for your time and solutions!